# Android studio usb debugging

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio USB debugging is not working with USB tethering! I want to test my application but I'm not able to do it because in Android Studio ADB my device is showing null there!

Comment: Is your device unlocked and is usb debugging enabled? You can read more here https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device

Answer (score 1):

**Turn on your USB debugging from Developer option also turn on Install via USB.**